# Delete with join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

I've searched answers but could not find what I am doing wrong, I keep getting an error on;

```
DELETE 
FROM kp_postmeta 
JOIN kp_posts 
ON kp_postmeta.post_id = kp_posts.ID
WHERE (kp_posts.post_type = 'flamingo_inbound' AND kp_posts.post_date < '2014-12-31')
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: whats the error your getting? what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify from which tables you want to delete after `delete`. If from both then it would look like this

```
DELETE kp_postmeta, kp_posts 
FROM kp_postmeta 
JOIN kp_posts ON kp_postmeta.post_id = kp_posts.ID
WHERE kp_posts.post_type = 'flamingo_inbound' 
AND kp_posts.post_date < '2014-12-31'
```